# how to create multiple directory in web services using json?

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, c#-4.0

i m trying to create multiple directory  using json. how to do this in asp.net .
my  connection class make a mathod of jsonspselect . but i m using the multiple root directory in asp.net

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetPropSubType()
    {
        try
        {
            objutl = new clsUtility();
            JSON_Out = objutl.JSONspselect("lspw_PropSubType ");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            JSON_Out = "Server Error";
        }
        finally
        { 
        }
        //string json = "{\"name\":\"Joe\"}";
        //Response.Clear();
        //Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        //Response.Write(JSON_Out);
        //Response.End();
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        Context.Response.Output.Write(JSON_Out);
        Context.Response.End();
        return JSON_Out;

    }
```

Comment: @LiranElisha   i want to create multiple directory in web service using json